# Code not being performed before function in if-statement

Tags: python, spyder

I am trying to run an if-statement where once a number 1 to 7 is selected the corresponding financial data is uploader as ticker. However, in my if-statement the code to import the data is not being run and it jumps directly to the function main_2(). Both the function main_2() and the code to import financial data as ticker and then just keep the 'Close' run perfect seperately but when put together in the if-statement main_2() only runs.
I am using spyder to run this program.

```
import yahoofinance as yf 
def main_():
    print("Choose dataset")
    print("1.Amazon \n2.Apple \n3.Cisco \n4.Meta \n5.Microsoft \n6.Qualcomm \n7.Starbucks")
    choice = input("Please choose option: ")
    if choice == '1':
        ticker = yf.Ticker('AMZN')
        ticker = ticker.history(period="5y")
        ticker_ = ticker[['Close']]
        print('1.Descriptive Analytics \n2.Visual Analysis \n3.Predictive Analysis')
        main_2()
    if choice == '2':
        ticker = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
        ticker = ticker.history(period="5y")
        ticker_ = ticker[['Close']]
        print('1.Descriptive Analytics \n2.Visual Analysis \n3.Predictive Analysis')
        main_2()
    if choice == '3':
        ticker = yf.Ticker('CSCO')
        ticker = ticker.history(period="5y")
        ticker_ = ticker[['Close']]
        print('1.Descriptive Analytics \n2.Visual Analysis \n3.Predictive Analysis')
        main_2()
    if choice == '4':
        ticker = yf.Ticker('META')
        ticker = ticker.history(period="5y")
        ticker_ = ticker[['Close']]
        print('1.Descriptive Analytics \n2.Visual Analysis \n3.Predictive Analysis')
        main_2()
    if choice == '5':
        ticker = yf.Ticker('MSFT')
        ticker = ticker.history(period="5y")
        ticker_ = ticker[['Close']]
        print('1.Descriptive Analytics \n2.Visual Analysis \n3.Predictive Analysis')
        main_2()
    if choice == '6':
        ticker = yf.Ticker('QCOM')
        ticker = ticker.history(period="5y")
        ticker_ = ticker[['Close']]
        print('1.Descriptive Analytics \n2.Visual Analysis \n3.Predictive Analysis')
        main_2()
    if choice == '7':
        ticker = yf.Ticker('SBUX')
        ticker = ticker.history(period="5y")
        ticker_ = ticker[['Close']]
        print('1.Descriptive Analytics \n2.Visual Analysis \n3.Predictive Analysis')
        main_2()
    
def main_2():        
    typ = input('Choose type of analysis:')
    if typ == '1':
        print(ticker_.describe())
        main_()
    elif typ == '2':
        print('1.Moving Averages \n2.Scatter plot \n3.Trend Lines')
        main_3()
    elif typ == '3':
        predictive()
        main_()
def main_3(): 
    graphical = input('Choose sort of graphical analysis:')
    if graphical == '1':
        moving_averages()
        main_4()
    elif graphical == '2':
        scatter_plot()
        main_4()
    elif graphical == '3':
        trend_line()
        main_4()
def main_4():
    print('1.Return to Main Menu \n2.Quit')
    option = input('Choose option:')
    if option == '1':
        main_()
    elif option == '2':
        quit()

main()
```

Comment: Your code is very repetitious. Why not use a dictionary keyed by `'1', '2'` etc. and whose values are `'AMZN'` etc.? In effect, you are using a series of `if` statements to implement an inefficient dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You should have this error: `NameError: name 'ticker' is not defined`

Call main_2 with ticker as a parameter: `main_2(ticker)`
In order to test it you can print `ticker` in main_2 to see if it works properly.

```
def main_2(ticker): 
    print(ticker)
```